duplicate columns with AWK and separate them by tab
I have a large file with the following format tab-separated:
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  recombination
chr1    586001  >63041388>63041391      G       A       60      .       AC=80;AF=0.3125;AN=256;AT=>63041388>63041390>63041391,>63041388>63041389>63041391;NS=3;LV=0     GT    1|2|3|

Now, the last column the 10th one appears as many numbers divided by a pipe |; however, what I wish to achieve is the following:
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  recombination
chr1    586001  >63041388>63041391      G       A       60      .       AC=80;AF=0.3125;AN=256;AT=>63041388>63041390>63041391,>63041388>63041389>63041391;NS=3;LV=0     GT    1|1    2|2    3|3

I managed to separate the columns with tab by replacing the | symbol, that leaves me with how to duplicate them and add back the | between numbers. I attempted few times with for loops but the best I can do is printing only two columns as such:
1    1
2    2
3    3
...

otherwise with printf I get a one-line output but cannot keep the counter the same value of the initial column...
Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

This should do it:
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '
    /^[^#]/{
     gsub("\\|","\t",$10)
     gsub("[0-9]+","&|&\t",$10) 
    }
   1' file.vcf 

Explanation

awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t': set the input (-F '\t') and output (-v OFS='\t') field separators to a tab.
/^[^#]/{ ... }: on lines that do not start with a #, i.e. non-header lines.
gsub("\\|","\t",$10);: replace all | in the 10th field with tabs.
gsub("[0-9]+","&|&\t",$10): now replace all sets of digits with themselves (& is replaced by whatever was matched), a | and then themselves again and a tab.
/^[^#]/{ ... }1': the default action of awk when something evaluates to true is to print the current record (line), so this 1, which always evaluates to true (non-0) and is outside the /^[^#]/{} conditional, will print every line.

This is what it looks like on your data (showing only the first few fields for clarity):
$ awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '/^[^#]/{gsub("\\|","\t",$10); gsub("[0-9]+","&|&\t",$10) }1' file.vcf | cut -f 1-50
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  recombination
chr1    586001  >63041388>63041391  G   A   60  .   AC=80;AF=0.3125;AN=256;AT=>63041388>63041390>63041391,>63041388>63041389>63041391;NS=3;LV=0 GT  1|1     2|2     3|3     4|4     5|5     6|6     7|7     8|8     9|9     10|10       11|11       12|12       13|13       14|14       15|15       16|16       17|17       18|18       19|19       20|20       21|21

Note that this is not a valid VCF and you will also need to have a sample name on the #CHROM header for each genotype listed so that tools designed to consume VCFs can deal with it correctly.

many thanks, I could manage to get to point 3, but I didn't know about that use of gsub and &. Indeed, is very clever and possibly better than a loop; also, thanks a lot for the detailed explanation

-F '\t' -v OFS='\t' is not in the code at the top of the answer.

Thanks, @Barmar, I'd forgotten.

Using awk:
$ awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '
          !/^#/{
          split($10,a,/\|/);
          for(i=1;i in a;i++) $10 = (i==1 ? "" : $10 OFS) a[i]"|"a[i]
        }1'


Input -Field separator and OFS Output Field Separator are set to \tab.
Field $10 is split to array by p|pe as sep.
Thereafter $10 is recreated using for loop. There in no need to find number of elements of array i.e.,n=split(..). When for loop is used as for(i=1;i in a;i++) then i in a would take care of number of elements of an array. ( Thanks to @EdMorton).
1 is true always that prints the current record. In fact, anything is truth but empty string or zero.

